# Set container name for a datasource devservice in quarkus?

Tags: containers, quarkus, testcontainers

I have a test setup that starts 2 postgres devservices. With the default configuration, I am not able to differ the two running containers until I connect to them and have a look at the existing tables. I was looking for a property to configure the container name of a datasource devservice, but couldn't find any.

How can I set the container name of a datasource devservice in quarkus, so that I am apple to tell which is which?

Comment: Testcontainers does not seem to allow that. However I do think it would make sense to add labels to the containers that would allow people to filter them. Would you like to open a Github issue asking for something like that?

Comment: Lables would already be enough. I'll open a issue. Thanks

Comment: Did you create the issue with Testcontainers, or with Quarkus? I think labels are a very good idea to solve this use case, without having the actual problem of container name, which can lead to conflicts.

Comment: @KevinWittek I did open a issue with quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/28857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Quarkus `2.15`, a `datasource` labels is added to database related containers.

See [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/28949) for more information.